# Problem with precision of fraction numbers

Tags: summation, precision-and-accuracy

I have tried to take a series of harmonic numbers using *Mathematica* and its precision but there has been an issue.

So far when I computed the sums at a whole numbers using a precision of 100 digits I get the actual answer:

```
1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[7`100, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 1000}]
(* Out: -1.868999598223701053846038076059845120154764132531047620125078549115461178796083  *)
```

However when I take a fractional value of 1.2 with a precision of 100 I get...

```
1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2`100, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 1000}]
(* Out: 0``-185.11918423420613 *)
```

Even if I take the precision up to 10000, I get:

```
1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2`10000, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 1000}]
(* Out: -4.56046017401129109343772345210743626064228....×10^156*)
```

Why is this the case? Could be that I have used mathemtica beta online? **Is there a way of getting the actual answer without taking the precision to millions of digits?**

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to use infinite precision numbers rather than finite. For example:

```
q = Total[(-1)^Range[1000] Table[HarmonicNumber[n], {n, 1000}]]
```

gives a very long fraction. Taking N[ ] of this gives 3.39641. Taking N[q,1000] gives it to 1000 digits, etc.

Comment: So then how do you get that without substituting any number for n? If I wanted to substitute 3.5 into my equation how would that be possible?

Comment: @Arbuja - Use `Rationalize`

Comment: @bill s I tried your technique but it didn't work. I used......

Comment: I used `q=Total[(-1)^Range[1000] Table[HarmonicNumber[7,-2*(2*n+1)], {n, 1000}]]` and got `0``-9339.452026231627`

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. When I do `q=Total[(-1)^Range[1000] Table[HarmonicNumber[7,-2*(2*n+1)], {n, 1000}]]//N` I get a very large number: 1.208301442749174*10^3382 .